# Wrap text around the buttons

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

How the text can be wrapped around the buttons. The buttons should be on right, inline with the text. I have used float but it is not working for my solution

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="product-item py-3 clearfix">
  <div>
    <p class="mb-0">Edu USA E-mails EDU e-mail accounts with GMAIL interface. You should login through </p>
  </div>
  <div class="float-right">
    <span class="badge badge-success mr-1">Buy</span>
    <span class="badge badge-primary mr-1">3402</span>
    <span class="badge badge-primary ">$8.40</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you want to make them inline, just move the `<span>`s into the first `<div>`.

Comment: Move the button div before the paragraph div

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="product-item py-3 clearfix">
  <div class="float-right">
    <span class="badge badge-success mr-1">Buy</span>
    <span class="badge badge-primary mr-1">3402</span>
    <span class="badge badge-primary ">$8.40</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p class="mb-0">Edu USA E-mails EDU e-mail accounts with GMAIL interface. You should login through </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: This make the buttons at the top of the text not inline with the text

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you look for ? *(snippets not avalaible with comment)*

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="product-item py-3 clearfix d-flex align-items-center">
  <div>
    <p class="mb-0">Edu USA E-mails EDU e-mail accounts with GMAIL interface. You should login through </p>
  </div>
  <div class="float-right">
    <span class="badge badge-success mr-1">Buy</span>
    <span class="badge badge-primary mr-1">3402</span>
    <span class="badge badge-primary ">$8.40</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: these button should not break into another line

Comment: also if the buttons are not float to right when text is less

Comment: @IhtishamKhan  float has no effect anymore, since the parent is a flex box so they stick at the end of the text : do you need them always on the right ? if yes, look again at the documentation of bootsrap to find out which class you need. they should stay on a single line, then again, the d-flex class can be used to turn them into flex children. This answer was about a comment whith a working example to put you on a right track. You have to learn a bit the basics of bootstrap to use it if learning CSS is too long for you ;)